# Someone hired by our company faked his expertise, how can I have legal or physical evidence on it

Tags: ethics, human-resources

He is in a very big position in the company, but me and my colleagues know he is fake because he doesn't have the basic technical knowledge of our industry, while his LinkedIn page shows that he held a lot of technical positions in many big companies worldwide, which is absolutely against logic.
He is causing our company huge losses and a lot of problems. The sad thing is, top management still believe in him.

I tried to find any history about him on the Internet but there is absolutely no traces for him except LinkedIn.

I used search engines that specifically search Internet for people, but with no luck.

**Is there any methodological way that HR people use to spot an imposter like this?** I prefer if there is something that can be done only by myself without using the help of other people.

Comment: Are you HR? If not, why do you think it's your place to oust him?

Comment: You're also assuming the people in senior technical positions in other companies automatically have technical knowledge. This, quite often, is not the case to the extent you might expect.

Comment: If you really care, get a private investigator. They are trained to do this research and if they come up with nothing, nobody has to know. If they do find anything, you then have evidence. However, truly I think this should be handled by HR or someone else who has better expertise in these types of problems.

Comment: **I'm closing this as off-topic** because I believe that this site shouldn't encourage a witch-hunt or give advice for what is essentially [doxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxing). The answers below *are* useful and look at the potentially fallacious reasoning that inspired this post but ultimately don't really answer the question. And that's a good thing because I don't believe we want or need to see actual answers for that question here. Please cast reopen votes or discuss on [meta] if you disagree.

Comment: The accusations in your questions sound vague, so you may better mind your own business.

Comment: @Lilienthal I agree, I probably should have VTC, but I felt the information provided was needed as a wake up call

Comment: @SaggingRufus Yeah like I said those answers are useful, but it's problematic to keep open in its present state. Some people are seeing this as a sort of XY problem: "Q: I'm trying to do X >> A: Here's why you shouldn't do X". And others think the general "*How does HR or a hiring copmany check for liars or inflated experience?*". And with the way this was worded both types of answer didn't really fit the question. I think this should perhaps be discussed on meta.

Answer (score 12):

**If you're going to take a shot, you better hit.**

You are basically accusing a senior of fraud and by the sounds of it and you don't even know what qualifications were required when he got the job. You will find more often than not, managers and higher-ups are not "retired" coders who moved up in the company. Instead, they are actually managers who actually don't know a lot of tech but are really good at their job. They hire good people beneath them and know how to motivate them.

Instead of pointing fingers and trying to ruin this guys job, why don't you be more productive with your time and just show the company (through your work) that this guy may not be up to snuff. Give it your all on every project you work on and make the results speak for themselves.

As I opened this answer with, if you're going to take a swing at this guy you better hit and 100% confidence that your evidence is enough. If it's not, I am going to take a wild guess and say you may be job hunting.

To address you final part of the question, HR would normally look for a diploma/degree and reference checks to gauge this persons experience.

Instead of assuming this guy must be an imposter, you may want to consider than he was probably hired under a different criteria than you were. So not an imposter at all.

Answer (score 4):

> He is in a very big position in the company, but me and my colleagues know he is fake because he doesn't have the basic technical knowledge of our industry, while his LinkedIn page shows that he held a lot of technical positions in many big companies worldwide, which is absolutely against logic.

I'm afraid it's your logic here that's incorrect - it's certainly possible to hold "high up" management positions without knowing direct, in depth technical details of the workings of the industry that you're in. Whether that *should* be the case is another question entirely of course, but that's irrelevant in this instance.

Regardless, there's nothing you can or should do in this situation. Perhaps management are right - after all, they have much more information about this situation than you do, and it's more than possible there's a few things you've missed that means you're attributing outcomes to him that aren't actually his fault.

Or perhaps management are wrong and they are beset on this guy, in which case they're not going to listen to you complaining about him (and using work time to try to dig up dirt on the guy is going to land you in hot water, not him.)

From what I've read, there's nothing to be gained from trying to oust this guy - if you really think he's going to drag the company under in the next few years, and you're absolutely convinced by this, then your best bet is probably to put your money where your mouth is and seek employment elsewhere.